# Helping wound healing after taking a cutting from monstera?

Tags: plant-health, cuttings, monstera

I have just taken a cutting from a healthy monstera deliciosa. I am concerned about the open wound left on the original plant, though, as it is exposed and leaking water.

I have read that given good conditions the plant will naturally heal itself, but is there anything I can do to help the plant recover?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No - sealants or wound paints are not recommended because they increase the risk of infection rather than reduce it. The sap which is bleeding out will eventually stop and the wound should callous over naturally.